# Swift function does not return soon enough

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, parse-platform

I'm trying to move my app over to MVC, I have a Parse query which I've moved over to a function in my model class, the function returns a Bool.

When the button in my ViewController below is pressed the model function 'parseQuery' should be run, return a bool and then I need to use that bool to continue. At the moment, the if statement is executed before the function has completed so it always detects false.

How can I ensure that the if statement is completed once the function has completed?

```
@IBAction func showAllExpiredUsers(sender: AnyObject) {

    var success = searchResults.parseQuery()

    if success {
        print("true")
    } else {
        print("false")
    }
    //I have also tried:

    searchResults.parseQuery()

    if searchResults.parseQuery() {
        print("true")
    } else {
        print("false")
    }
```

Comment: have you tried putting the function to `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: is parseQuery() a function you created?  This isn't in the parse API

Comment: let me gues - the function is asynchronous?

Comment: Thanks everyone, having it in the viewDidLoad wouldn't work as it needs to be called at different times to return updated results. parseQuery() is the name of my function which contains a regular 'findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock'. I haven't touched the syncronisation so I guess it would be asynchronous by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options, but the issue is due to asynchronous calls.

Does Parse expose the same function, with a completion block?

If yes, then you place the processing of the Bool inside the completion block, which is called when the async task is completed.

If not, which I doubt, you could create an NSOperationQueue, with a maxConcurrency of 1 (so it is serial) and dispatch the calls onto the queue with

[func addOperationWithBlock(_ block: () -> Void)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperationQueue/addOperationWithBlock:)

This is called on the queue. You would need to store the success bool globally so that you can access it inside the second queued block operation, to check the success state.

**Update:**

I haven't used parse, but checking the documentation for findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock (https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries) it takes a completion block where you can process the result, update your bool.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do. You don't need to have the success state of the query. You can check

```
if (!error) { 
   // do stuff 
} else { 
  //error occurred - print("error \(error.localizedDescription)"
}
```

Check the example.

What you need to understand is threading. The async task provides a completion block because its asynchronous, it gets dispatched onto another thread for processing. I'm not sure how much you know about threading but there is something called a thread pool. This thread pool is accessed by Queues. The thread pool is managed by the OS, and makes sure available threads can be used by queues that need work done. As users interact with an application, this (and all UI work) is done on the main thread.

So whenever some processing is going to interfere with possible interaction or UI updates, it should be dispatched (Grand Central Dispatch) or queued (NSOperationQueue, built on top of GCD) off of the main thread.

Anyway, this is why the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` call is dispatched off the main thread, because otherwise it would block the main thread until its done, ruining the experience for the user. Also, if the main thread is blocked for more than 1 minute (last time I checked), the OS's watchdog will kill your process.

So yeah, assigning a boolean to the return of the block, would get the return of the function, which occurs before the completion block is done. The completion block is where you code some stuff to be done after the function completes. So the query gets dispatched onto another thread and starts processing, the thread that sent this work off for processing, continues with the rest of its execution. So checking the boolean directly after, wouldn't work because the other thread isn't complete. Even if the other thread finished in time, what is connecting the background thread with the main thread?

This is the beauty of blocks (function pointers), it's a lot cleaner and optimized and keeps code compact. The old way, which is still is use for some older frameworks, is delegates, which detaches the calling code with the callback and adds a delegate dependency. Blocks are beautiful.

Its also important to note that completion blocks don't always get called on the main thread. In many cases its up to you to dispatch the work back to the main thread, to handle any UI work that needs to be done with the objects available inside the completion block.

Comment: Great reply, thank you. Can you explain what you mean by 'expose the same function'?. My function is a regular findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock, I have tried updating the Bool from within the completion block but this happens just after the nick of time. I have been swatting up on addOperationWithBlock, hopefully this will help but it's not working yet

Comment: I really appreciate the detailed response, it's made things far clearer. It sounds like I might need to keep my queries in the Controller rather than the Model. The reason I needed to return the Bool was actually to say if true then display alert and if false display error alert, the issue was I couldn't successfully call alerts from the model, I'm assuming this is not possible but if it is then do let me know. Thanks again.

Comment: I just tried a work around which actually worked. I simply called the function and had the function update a global Bool. Then run a delay function for two seconds before actioning the if/else, it worked and triggered the alerts... good to see it work but unfortunately it's not really viable.

Comment: @BenSullivan - sorry for delayed response. So when it comes to architecture, blocks can be passed down the chain. So a common example is your controller calls an interface on the model, which takes a completion block. You can add a completion block to your controllers interface so your VC's calls the function on the controller, passing in a completion block that uses the available variables in the completion block, e.g. response, error, and then displays an alert view. You controller can interface with the model, passing the completion block sent from the VC directly to the model's function.

Comment: When the model is done, it calls completion with arguments, which will trigger the block passed through the controller from the VC. You could also send a block to the model from the controller, i.e. with more parameters, so you can intercept the callback from the model, inside the controller (e.g. network object) which then calls the block from the VC once its done what it needs to, finally the VC completion block is called and the alert displayed. E.g. syncing data with server. UI control>network controller>pass downloaded data to model>success>notify server> call VC completion block

Answer (score 0):

The query likely takes some time to run and should be run in a background thread with a callback function to handle the response WHEN it completes.

look at the [Documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries)

Specifically looking at the `query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` code:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")
query.whereKey("playerName", equalTo:"Sean Plott")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

  if error == nil {
    // The find succeeded.
    print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
    // Do something with the found objects
    if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
      for object in objects {
        print(object.objectId)
      }
    }
  } else {
    // Log details of the failure
    print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
  }
}
```

The above code will execute the query and run the code in the block when it gets the results from Parse. This is known as an asynchronous task, for more information check out [this guide](http://www.raywenderlich.com/79149/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-1)

Comment: Thanks, this is how I am currently doing it, however the block is not completed soon enough.